# Scrollview with big custom view and smaller textviews

Tags: android, scrollview, android-custom-view

I am trying to make a scrollable layout, where I would have a single bigger custom view at the start and dynamic amount of smaller TextViews after it.

Like this:

```
|-----|---Start of devices screen
|     |
|     | -Custom view 1
|     |
|-----|
|     |---TextView & End of devices screen
|-----|
|-----|
|     |
|-----|
```

The custom view is a view where I do some drawing in onDraw().

I have been trying to fiddle with the onMeasure() method, layout_height and layout_weight properties, but I am unable to get a satisfactory result. I always end up with a unscrollable layout or one without the custom view. Only way I have been able to get the functionality is by setting the custom view's height to some 'dp' value, but I would like it leave the same physical amount of space in the botto of the screen.

Is something like this possible with the tools Android provides, or would this need some custom view for the scrolling too? How would I go about implementing this?

Edit: To clarify, I need the first element I have in the ScrollView to initially either fill the whole visible area of the ScrollView or leave a small space under it that is constant on every device.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flow Layout In place of your custom layout 
find flow layout implementation link

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_VKZCqEnHblNDdiY2UxODgtYWNhNS00MmU4LWE4NDMtZjQ1OWI5MDMxZTVh/edit?num=50&sort=name&layout=list&pli=1#

```
package com.example.android.layout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FlowLayout extends ViewGroup {
    private int mHorizontalSpacing;
    private int mVerticalSpacing;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public FlowLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FlowLayout);
        try {
            mHorizontalSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.FlowLayout_horizontalSpacing, 0);
            mVerticalSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.FlowLayout_verticalSpacing, 0);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) - getPaddingRight();
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);

        boolean growHeight = widthMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED;

        int width = 0;
        int height = getPaddingTop();

        int currentWidth = getPaddingLeft();
        int currentHeight = 0;

        boolean breakLine = false;
        boolean newLine = false;
        int spacing = 0;

        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            spacing = mHorizontalSpacing;
            if (lp.horizontalSpacing >= 0) {
                spacing = lp.horizontalSpacing;
            }

            if (growHeight && (breakLine || currentWidth + child.getMeasuredWidth() > widthSize)) {
                height += currentHeight + mVerticalSpacing;
                currentHeight = 0;
                width = Math.max(width, currentWidth - spacing);
                currentWidth = getPaddingLeft();
                newLine = true;
            } else {
                newLine = false;
            }

            lp.x = currentWidth;
            lp.y = height;

            currentWidth += child.getMeasuredWidth() + spacing;
            currentHeight = Math.max(currentHeight, child.getMeasuredHeight());

            breakLine = lp.breakLine;
        }

        if (!newLine) {
            height += currentHeight;
            width = Math.max(width, currentWidth - spacing);
        }

        width += getPaddingRight();
        height += getPaddingBottom();

        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(width, widthMeasureSpec),
                resolveSize(height, heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            child.layout(lp.x, lp.y, lp.x + child.getMeasuredWidth(), lp.y + child.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
        boolean more = super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        if (lp.horizontalSpacing > 0) {
            float x = child.getRight();
            float y = child.getTop() + child.getHeight() / 2.0f;
            canvas.drawLine(x, y - 4.0f, x, y + 4.0f, mPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, x + lp.horizontalSpacing, y, mPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(x + lp.horizontalSpacing, y - 4.0f, x + lp.horizontalSpacing, y + 4.0f, mPaint);
        }
        if (lp.breakLine) {
            float x = child.getRight();
            float y = child.getTop() + child.getHeight() / 2.0f;
            canvas.drawLine(x, y, x, y + 6.0f, mPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(x, y + 6.0f, x + 6.0f, y + 6.0f, mPaint);
        }
        return more;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean checkLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
        return p instanceof LayoutParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
        return new LayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
        return new LayoutParams(p.width, p.height);
    }

    public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams {
        int x;
        int y;

        public int horizontalSpacing;
        public boolean breakLine;

        public LayoutParams(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FlowLayout_LayoutParams);
            try {
                horizontalSpacing = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.FlowLayout_LayoutParams_layout_horizontalSpacing, -1);
                breakLine = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.FlowLayout_LayoutParams_layout_breakLine, false);
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
            }
        }

        public LayoutParams(int w, int h) {
            super(w, h);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="FlowLayout">
        <attr name="horizontalSpacing" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="verticalSpacing" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="FlowLayout_LayoutParams">
        <attr name="layout_breakLine" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="layout_horizontalSpacing" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Tried copying the Flowlayout class and the style to my project, but I am getting 'android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.android.layout.FlowLayout'.

Comment: Please change package name  "com.example.android.layout.FlowLayout" to your package  project name

Comment: Thanks, that got it inflating. Do you mean for me to use the Flowlayout inside the ScrollView? I am still forced to give the custom view a constant height in dip for it to render properly with the other elements. I need the custom view to always fill the whole screen of the device, but still let the user scroll and see the other views at the bottom.

Comment: Yes You can add within Scrollview if Height of FlowLayout goes out off Screen Height

Comment: What benefit does this give to me instead of a LinearLayout? I would need the custom view to be the only thing the user sees when opening the activity, but setting 'android:layout_height="match_parent"' makes the scrolling unworking. Setting a constant size in 'dp' would make it different size in different devices.

Comment: take Relativelayout (root)-> ScrollView (alignparenttop and above textview)-.>Flowlayout -> ScrollviewEnds> <-TextView  alignparentbottom> ,I think you must take view in this order .FlowLayout Given solution to add any number of child views withing Flowlayout and it handles it self.

Comment: How would I set the size of my custom view to initially fill the visible area of the ScrollView? I am able to get the hierarchy right even with a LinearLayout, but the size of the first element is the problem.

Comment: if you are trying to do this with customView then you need to calculate inner and outer padding or margins if you have added into Customview or in ChildViews , Because each time when you  calculate views width to change new line its given wrong value .